# insert ignore or replace ignore not working

Tags: mysql

I'm moving data from one SQL table to a second table using
`insert ignore or replace into`
I isn't working, I believe because I don't have a unique key. I also don't know where I would put the key.

I need the second table to display the last `zone` the `number` was seen on that `date`. I can add a time column if needed.

Example Data:

| number | zone | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | zone3 | 01-02-03 |
| 1 | zone1 | 01-02-03 |
| 1 | zone3 | 01-02-03 |
| 2 | zone1 | 01-02-03 |
| 3 | zone2 | 01-02-03 |

- If I put `number` as a unique key it doesn't get added when the date changes.
- If I add date as a unique key only one row gets added on that date.

The query:

```
REPLACE INTO database.table2 (number,zone,date)
    SELECT number,zone,date
    FROM database.table1
    GROUP BY number,date;
```

I hoped with the number and date grouped that it won't duplicate record, but it is still adding multiples.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want to achieve, but: if you don't have unique keys, then there is no need for either INSERT IGNORE or REPLACE. You can use plain INSERT (resulting in duplicates) or UPDATE (to change values of existing rows)

Comment: my overall goal is to add data from table 1 to table 2 where data is not inserted if it is already present in table 2 e.g. move beacon,zone,date from T1 to T2 where beacon is 1 zone is 1 date is 01-01-01 if beacon and date already exist in T2 where beacon is 1 and date is 01-01-01 dont insert

Comment: Ok, in this case if you set a unique constraint on the compound (beacon, date) in T2, then INSERT IGNORE should work.

Comment: Your unique key needs to consist of both columns. The group by ansatz might work too though (if you fix it a bit, and it needs to insert into an empty table, and it is unclear what `beacon` is). What I am not too sure about is how (and if at all) you decide which of your source rows for the same date is the last row for that day (or is it a datetime in the first table?)

Comment: So I have made both number and date but it is only added 1 value due to date being a UQ value and sorry beacon is number.

Comment: also date is pulled in from the 1st table the date and time gets added with the number value as it is inputted into the database table 1

Comment: You need to *only* have the composite unique key, you need to remove the single column keys. The reason I asked about the time is that `insert ignore` will just take any row you have (e.g. if you have `1 zone1 01-02-03` and `1 zone2 01-02-03` in your first table, MySQL (and we) do not know which you consider "the last". MySQL will just take *any*, so you can end up with zone1 or zone2. You would need to clarify that to us, but most importantly to MySQL. You should add some sample data of your first table to clear up some of the questions (e.g. time and the beacon-value)